# How to compile multiple JARs with GraalVM native image

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

All usage guides show how to run `native-image` on a single JAR file. But I believe most projects usually use multiple JARs on classpath (e.g. Gradle default way). How to tell native-image to bundle all of them into one executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the class path to use for building the executable:

```
-cp, -classpath, --class-path <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>: a separated list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search for class files.
```

Here's more docs about various options to the `native-image` utility: https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/Options/

All in all it should `native-image -cp this.jar:that.jar -jar myjar.jar`

Comment: Hi, I use maven-assembly-plugin to produce a folder containing multiple jars. Libraries are put into libs folder, properties files and xml files are put into another folder etc. How can I feed this into graal so it produces an image with all jars combined? should I specify every jar one by one or can I just give -cp "./libs/*"